# Proving that a real function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions

Let $y$ be a real function and $c>0$. If $y$ satisfies the following inequality
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(t)+y(t)\leq y^{\frac{3}{2}}(t)+c
\end{equation}
How can I prove that $y$ is bounded.

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: I derivate both terms of inequality

Comment: Is there any Condition in terms of the domain of $f(t)$?
Because if you take $f(t)=t$, $\alpha=3$ and $c=10$
,The inequality holds but $t$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.
Also, taking the derivative on both sides of the inequality doesn't work since
$f(x)>g(x)$ doesn't mean that $f'(x)>g'(x)$. You can take $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=-e^{-x}$ as an example.

Comment: Is the question coming from some textbook or assignment? Please provide relevant context (including source, your background, your own ideas for solution) for the benefit of users. The question in its present form runs the risk of getting closed.

Comment: I think showing that $f(t)$ is bounded if the right-hand side is bounded is more useful. It's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is false by $f(x)=x$. Then $x\le 10+ \int_0^x s^2 ds= 10+ \frac13 x^3$.

Comment: (+1) I do not follow your argument but your counterexample is correct: $1+t\le t^{3/2}+2.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval
The host changed the question. This is a counterexample of his/her original problem.