# How to solve the differential equation $y^{\prime}(t)+y(t)=y^{\frac{3}{2}}(t)+c$, where $c$ is a constant. Prove that $y$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

How can I solve this differential equation
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(t)+y(t)=y^{\frac{3}{2}}(t)+c
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant. A solution $y$ of this differential equation is bounded or not?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Moreover, you already received a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557653), 8 hours before your present post.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= y^{\frac{3}{2}}-y+c \\
\frac{dy}{y^{3/2}-y+c} &= dt
\end{align}

Let $x=y^{1/2}$ and $2xdx=dy$.

L.H.S. can be turned into a fraction of polynomials. If $c$ is known, it is workable by partial fraction. Otherwise, you may need to leave it in integral form.

Comment: Please How can you show me the all steps  to arrive in a solution

Comment: A solution $y$ of this differential equation is bounded or not?